# Correct use of chi-squared for categorical data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, multiple-comparisons

I am trying to do a hypothesis test with some categorical data; I initially thought a chi-squared test may be appropriate, but perhaps I am mistaken.

The experiment is as follows.  I have four samples A-D, of the same type.  A is the reference.  There are two outcomes, negative or positive.  For the reference A, all outcomes are positive.  B is a treatment I know should pretty much give all negative results.  Finally, C-D are the type of sample as A to which I did differing treatments after treatment B; I am essentially trying to determine which of C or D "undoes" treatment B.

```
Observed:   A   B   C   D   totals
neg:        0   14  15  1   30
pos:       34   1   4   23  62
totals:    34   15  19  24  92
```

I would assume my expectations would be as follows:

```
Expected:   A   B   C   D   totals
neg:        0   15  0   0   15
pos:       34   0   19  24  77
totals:    34   15  19  24  92
```

During the calculation of $(Obs-Exp)^2/Exp$, I used a small value 0.01 for the expected so that I do not divide by infinity.  That gives me the following table
of chi-squareds.

```
Chi.sq: A        B          C           D
neg:    0.01    0.066666667 22470.01    98.01
pos:    0       98.01       11.84210526 0.041666667
```

I am confused at this point, intuitively, looking at the data, A and B seem "correct", while I would say treatment C is not working but treatment D is.
I think it stems from how I define a null versus alternative hypothesis.  Any help on setting up this problem more properly, of if there is a better test I should use?

Comment: Where exactly did the values in your "table of chi-squareds" come from?

Comment: The prospect of division by zero should alert you that what you are doing is invalid.  By putting those zeros in the expectations table you basically have asserted that certain things definitely should not happen--but they did.  There's no need for a test; your observations *prove* your expectations are wrong.

Comment: @whuber: To clarify, this is probably instrumentation error.  Unfortunately, there can be false positives, this data is "pre filtered" by some other checks but sometimes there are such readings that get through.

Comment: @gung:  I calculated these by taking $(Observed-Expected)^2/Expected$ for each cell.

Comment: The crucial matter here is how you came up with the table of expected values--I believe that is what @gung was asking.  No amount of error should ever cause you to introduce a true zero into the expectation unless you are absolutely certain that cell will never occur.  I doubt we can be of much help until you explain this procedure.